# dollar neutral ratio vs beta hedged ratio

Tags: beta, ratio

Hi guys i really hope you can help as i've been pulling out my hair for days on this!!

OK so basically i understand the dollar neutral ratio, simply stocka/stockb = dollar neutral ratio. Works great because i can chart it and do a daily p/l update and it perfectly tracks the p/l of my whole long short position.

My questions is how do i get the ratio when the spread is weighted differently due to differing beta values? For example stocka is very volatile and stockb is not. So i will for arguments sake weight 80% of my capital on stocka and 20% of my capital on stock.

Now to get my ratio i can not simply divide the stocka by stockb as i did before because i get the same daily p/l swings.

So guys how do i get a beta hedged ratio which i can chart and also track a daily p/l which perfectly represents my whole long short position.

Appreciate all your time and energy, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just weight the p/l equation the same way your position is weighted? So:

`(P(StockA)*0.8)/(P(StockB)*0.2) = Net % change in the position`

Answer (score 0):

Take BCM's approach, or, weight your exposure (and PNL) by the stock beta within the equity index. To do this, run the least squares regression to determine BetaA:
'    '
    StockPriceA = const + BetaA * SectorEquityIndex + residual
    StockPriceB = const + BetaB * SectorEquityIndex + residual

You could then either trade one stock hedged at that beta against the index, or two stocks (A,B) hedged against one another with weights BetaA/BetaB.